# What is the relation between a callback and dto?

Tags: java, oop, callback, dto

From what i understand a Data Transfer Object  is virtually a callback object that has no methods. When you pass a callback you pass the data and attach operations to it. When you pass a DTO you just pass the properties. Right ?(we are strictly talking about java)

Comment: DTOs and callbacks don't really have anything to do with each other.

Comment: it's easier to differentiate in C++. To me in java implementation Callbacks look like DTOs with attached methods/operations/etc.

Comment: Well, Java is quite different from C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation between the two idioms.

A [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is just a different representation of a piece of data, often based on relational projection. Basic usage is for data transmission.

A [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) is just a way to pass a piece of code that must be call later on. Such as as listener which is invoke when some particular events occur. Basic usage is for behavior transmission.

Comment: so you have class1obj1.propertyA and class2obj1.propertyA and propertyB. You package the 3 in another object with no method and you have a DTO. You package them in another object that also has methods that operate on the the properties and you have a Callback object..Yeah DTO and callback have different definitons with regard to their purpose but implementation wise are there any oder differences, restrictions etc.?

Comment: Generally, DTO are only use to transmit data whereas callback are only use to transmit behaviour.

Comment: your comment should be answer

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not how I think about it.

A callback is a function that is called when a particular event fires.

A DTO is nothing more than a bad J2EE anti-pattern, a struct for moving data between layers.  It came into being because EJB 1.0 entity beans were found to be excessively "chatty" with the database, so some people would bring all the data back in one round trip and package it into a DTO for the UI to consume.

Comment: DTO technique is not only a J2EE concern and it can be use to represent some flatten projection without to return a whole complex object structure.
For example, it can be used to manage "analytic" queries.

Comment: Yup, I realize that.  It happens to have propagated deeply into Java thinking because of the "Core J2EE Patterns" book.  The question is tagged as Java.  I thought the emphasis was needed.  But your point is a good one: like all patterns, this one transcends language.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others already wrote here some common samples:

Callback sample: e.g. Listeners such as java.awt.event.ActionListener. (An ActionListener is used to run some code when the user presses a button)

DTO sample: e.g. JAXB classes generated from your WSDLs (SOAP Web Services)